# Create 2D Circle from Existing Grid

Tags: matrix, data-structures

We have a matrix:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to retain the data in these fields, but in the shape of a 2D-circle:

```
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 0
```

But this also scales up:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

What would the greatest way to approach this?

Comment: While it can be implemented using DSA without any advanced knowledge, if your application involves large grids I suggest using techniques from *Graphics & Visual Computing* such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/circle_generation_algorithm.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cy` and `cx` are center points
`r` is the radius
`tiles` is an empty grid

```
function MakeCircle(tiles, cx, cy, r):
    for x in range(cx - r, cx + r):
        for y in range(cy - r, cy + r):
            if (distance(cx, cy, x, y) <= r):
                tiles[x][y] = 1
    return(tiles)

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return(sqrt((x1 - x2)**2) + (y1 - y2)**2))
```

This dynamically creates a circle of ones in a square-matrix regardless of size of matrix.